# Displaying/Loading gui frames in order

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, windowbuilder

I have created 3 GUI frames using windowbuilder to be loaded and displayed in this order.

- 1st GUI (Home.java)
- 2nd GUI & 3rd GUI (Results1.java, Results2.java)

Obviously Home.java can be first loaded but the 2 proceeding GUIs load at the same time as the Home.java. I can verify it since I inserted a print syntax inside the method where I initializa the elements of the GUI. I can display the last 2 GUIs after pressing a button at Home.java but the content already loaded. So when I need to pass a variable to these 2 GUIs the value becomes null. Any ideas?

Home.Java button pressed.

```
//Compare Button
            btnCompare.addActionListener(
                        new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                            if(lbl_filecontainer1.getText() != "No File" && lbl_filecontainer2.getText() != "No File")
                            {

                                    r1.setFileName1(lbl_filecontainer1.getText());
                                    r1.Launch();
                            }
                            else if (lbl_filecontainer1.getText() == "No File" && lbl_filecontainer2.getText() != "No File")
                            {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No file 1 selected");
                            }
                            else if (lbl_filecontainer1.getText() != "No File" && lbl_filecontainer2.getText() == "No File")
                            {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No file 2 selected");
                            }
                            else
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No files selected");
                            }

                      }
                    );
```

Results1.java

```
public class Results1 {

private JFrame frmFileOverall;
String FileName1;

//Instances
Database db = new Database();

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public void Launch(String FileName) {
            try {
               setFileName1(FileName);
                Results1 window = new Results1();
                window.frmFileOverall.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Results1() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frmFileOverall = new JFrame();
    frmFileOverall.setResizable(false);
    frmFileOverall.setTitle("File 1 overall result");
    frmFileOverall.setBounds(100, 100, 550, 450);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Number of words: ");
    lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 11));

    JLabel lblNumberOfSentences = new JLabel("Number of sentences: ");
    lblNumberOfSentences.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 11));

    JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("Number of paragraphs: ");
    label_1.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 11));

    JTextArea txtAreaFile1 = new JTextArea();
    txtAreaFile1.setEditable(false);

    JLabel wordsContainerFile1 = new JLabel("New label");

    JLabel sentencesContainerFile1 = new JLabel("New label");

    JLabel paragraphsContainerFile1 = new JLabel("New label");
    GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(frmFileOverall.getContentPane());
    groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(txtAreaFile1, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 514, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(lblNewLabel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 124, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(wordsContainerFile1))
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(label_1)
                            .addComponent(lblNumberOfSentences, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 151, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(paragraphsContainerFile1)
                            .addComponent(sentencesContainerFile1))))
                .addContainerGap())
    );
    groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(lblNewLabel)
                    .addComponent(wordsContainerFile1))
                .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(lblNumberOfSentences)
                    .addComponent(sentencesContainerFile1))
                .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(label_1)
                    .addComponent(paragraphsContainerFile1))
                .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(txtAreaFile1, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 322, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
    );
    frmFileOverall.getContentPane().setLayout(groupLayout);
    System.out.print(getFileName1());
    //txtAreaFile1.setText(db.loadFile(getFileName()));
}

public void setFileName1(String fileName)
{
    this.FileName1 = fileName;
}

public String getFileName1()
{
    return this.FileName1;
}


}
```

Comment: Already tried to create the gui using a normal class. Still experiencing the same problem.

Comment: As a stated, I have 3 guis. I want to load and display the first gui and after clicking a button, the last 2 guis must load and display. The current state of my program loads all 3 guis at the same time but only displays the 1st one. Which is what I really intent to do, but not load the last two. Since the last two loaded with the 1st one, I can't pass variables to the last two guis since it was already loaded. Got it?

Comment: I think I figured it out. Please see answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than just display an already created results GUI on button push, why not simply create your results GUIs only when the button is pressed, i.e., have the results creation code called from the Home JButton's ActionListener? So again to summarize, the key seems to be when and how you *create* the results GUI's, and you seem to be doing this at program start, when you should be doing it in response to an event from the user.

Note that many here, myself included, would recommend that instead of shooting different windows at the user, you use just one JFrame as your GUI's view and change JPanels in this view using a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). Also, many here would recommend learning to code Swing GUI's first by hand before using code-generating tools such as Window Builder. This way you will better understand what the code-generating tools are doing under the hood if you later use them, and will make using them *much* easier.

---

**Edit 1**
Note, I'm not sure what you mean by:

> Already tried to create the gui using a normal class. Still experiencing the same problem.

What do you mean by "create the gui using a normal class"? They're all normal classes.

---

**Edit 2**
Your code is a bit schizophrenic in that you have a Results1 object creating a ***new*** Results1 object, and this is where you're messing up. Let's call the first Results1 object r1A and the second r1B. As I see it this is what's happening:

- r1A is created on program creation before the user has interacted with the GUI.
- When the user presses a JButton in your "home" GUI, ...
- r1A gets info from the user and uses this to set a String called fileName.
- r1A also creates a new Results1 object, r1B. This new object has no knowledge about the fileName String.
- r1A then tells r1B to display a JFrame, frmFileOverall, that again is ignorant about any changes made to r1A's fileName String.

My suggestions:

- Create one and only 1 Results1 object,
- not at program creation as you're doing, but again only when the button is pressed in the ActionListener code.
- Give Results1 a constructor String parameter so you can pass fileName into its *constructor*.
- Again, don't have Results1 create another Results1 object.
- Again, avoid use of any window builder software for the moment and go through the Java Swing tutorials as all of this will become second nature to you if you can first do this coding by hand.

---

**Edit 3**
Regarding your code:

```
if(lbl_filecontainer1.getText() != "No File" && 
    lbl_filecontainer2.getText() != "No File") {
    // ....
```

You don't want to compare Strings using `!=` or `==` since this will check if one String *object* is the same as another String *object*, something which can lead to misleading results. You instead want to know if two String objects contain the same text, and for that you'll want to use the String methods `equals(...)` or `equalsIgnoreCase(...)`:

```
if(!"No File".equalsIgnoreCase(lbl_filecontainer1.getText()) && 
    !"No File".equalsIgnoreCase(lbl_filecontainer2.getText())) {
    // ....
```

Comment: See my updated post. As you can see, the behavior of the code is just like what you said. "have the results creation code called from the Home JButton's ActionListener". But the Results1.java loads with Home.hava since the System.out.print inside the Results1.java is already displayed even if I haven't clicked my button.,

Comment: When creating a gui using a windowbuilder I create it by selecting others and application window. So the codes are automatically generated. I tried copying the code and pasting it to a normal class by just creating new class. That's what I meant.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Too bad we can't put zillion +1 ;)

Comment: I got your point there. But why does it print the System.out.print inside the results1.java at program start? I moved the creation of the object inside the JButton's ActionListener.

Comment: @ljpv: again you're creating the Results1 object *twice*, once at program start (probably) and once in the ActionListener.

Comment: @ljpv14 As far as I can see, there is no line `r1 = new Result1()` inside your `btn` ActionListener. All I can see is that you call `Launch()` inside that ActionListener, but your `initialize()` is called in `Result1` constructor, therefore, when you call `new Result1()`. Also, consider following Java naming convention, ie, a method should always start with a lower-case letter: instead of `Launch()` use `launch()`.

Comment: The behavior seems to pull it off that way. But the way I see my code makes me doubt it. Anyway thank you for the thorough explanations. You showered some ideas that I can ponder. Will try to do some alterations with my code. :)

Comment: @ljpv: the behavior doesn't lie. Best of luck with your project!

Comment: As I said in my comments, I already moved my object creation inside the btn Aciontlistener. Thank you for reminding me about naming convetion.:)

Comment: @ljpv: please see **Edit 3**.

Comment: Thank you again for the clarification. Finally made my program work. Thank you for the ideas.